# How to find gravity field of a solid square body?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, integration

I was programming gravity simulation and stumbled upon a problem, that Newton's formula for point masses is not enough for me, I need gravity field formula of a solid square body (2D).

To simplify things, I considered only square with corners at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ and constant density.

I tried to compute following integral ($x_b, y_b$ - coordinates of point-like body in the field):

$$F(x_b,y_b)=\int_0^1\int _0^1\frac{(x_b-x)\vec{i}+(y_b-y)\vec{j}}{\left(\left(x_b-x\right){}^2+\left(y_b-y\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}}dxdy$$

In the end I got sum of four logarithms with square roots inside for each component of $F$  (probably too ugly to be pasted here). At first glance, plot of function looked reasonable, but I found later, that it tends to infinity at square border. In contrast, formulas for gravity of solid sphere are finite everywhere (found them at Wikipedia). Intuition says, that gravity of square should be also finite everywhere, and that my calculation is wrong.

[image: Wrong gravity]

I though that due to singularity (division by zero if $(x_b,y_b)$ is inside square) integral diverges.

I don't know whether my calculation is incorrect or integral is incorrect or both. Please give me right direction to solve my problem. Note, that I need closed-form formula, if possible. Also, worth noting, that my physics and calculus knowledge is not very advanced, since I am studying Computer science.

Comment: Do you use Wolfram Mathematica for calculations?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, I do. However, it cannot numerically compute this integral or in symbolic form (with parameters). It even gives contradicting results for fixed values of $x_b,y_b$ inside square. Pretty strange integral... Function on the plot is found manually (though I think incorrectly, even though it looks reasonable).

Comment: Why do you consider 2D and not 3D?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am making simulation in 2D world. Already understood that 2D is my problem. Gravity does not work in 2D same way as in 3D. I need to go to 3D (gravity of solid box) or to change law of gravity (in my 2D world). Will make an answer about that soon.

Comment: For 3D box see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3857.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use [Gauss's law for gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity#Differential_form), $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{g}=-4\pi G\rho$.

Inside the thickness-$\tau$ square prism, a prism of the same thickness and infinitesimal base $dxdy$ has mass $\rho\tau dxdy$ and $gdxdy=\int\vec{g}\cdot dS =-4\pi G\rho\tau dxdy$.

Anywhere outside the square prism, $\rho=0$ so $\vec{g}$ is divergenceless. Thus $g$ doesn't change along a normal to the square. I'll leave you to contemplate the edge effects of the prism having finite size.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit simpler? I am not familiar with Gauss's law or divergence.

Comment: And why do you taking $\rho=0$ not on the surface? I have solid square, not square shell, I am sorry if that was not obvious from question, I will edit.

Comment: @Somnium I've updated too.

Comment: I see, thank you. However, I cannot understand how this helps to find formula. As understood from divergence definition, this gives us $g_x'(x,y)+g_y'(x,y)=-4\pi G\rho$, only one constraint. We need two constraints to find $g_x(x,y)$ and  $g_y(x,y)$, don't we?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, since there's no mass outside of the square we can use Laplace equation with boundary conditions to find the potential, and the square boundary can be changed by conformal mapping to something nice, like a circle.